# How to exclude from matrix items of a list?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix with multiple rows, and I want to remove some rows of matrix, including the name of the first column belong to a banned list should be ignored.

Like this:

```
Product name     number      color
P1                x            red
P1                x            blue
p1                x            blue
p2                x            red
p3                x            red
p4                x            red
p4                x            green

listItemToExclude = ['p1', 'p4']
```

I need to get this result:

```
Product name     number      color

p2                x            red
p3                x            red
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: your attempt? I will give you a hint, use `ismember` or `strcmp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your matrix is a cell array:

```
M = {'P1', 'x', 'red'; 'P1', 'x', 'blue'; 'p1', 'x', 'blue'; ...
     'p2', 'x', 'red'; 'p3', 'x', 'red'; 'p4', 'x', 'red'; 'p4', 'x', 'green'};
```

You can pick out the desired rows with [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
>> rowsOut = M(ismember(M(:,1),{'p2','p3'}),:)
rowsOut = 
    'p2'    'x'    'red'
    'p3'    'x'    'red'
```

Or you can use [`strcmpi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html) with [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to ignore case:

```
keyMatchFun = @(x) strcmpi(M(:,1),x);
keyMatchMasks = cellfun(keyMatchFun,{'p2','p3'},'uni',false);
rowsOut = M(any([keyMatchMasks{:}],2),:)
```

To add the header:

```
>> header = {'Product name','number','color'};
>> [header; outRows]
ans = 
    'Product name'    'number'    'color'
    'p2'              'x'         'red'  
    'p3'              'x'         'red'
```

EDIT: If you are starting with an exclude list, like `listItemToExclude = {'p1', 'p4'};`, you can get the list to include (ignoring case) via:

```
uniqueProducts = unique(lower(M(:,1)));
excludeMasks = cellfun(@(x)strcmpi(uniqueProducts,x),listItemToExclude,'uni',0);
listItemToInclude = uniqueProducts(~any([excludeMasks{:}],2))' %' use above
listItemToInclude = 
    'p2'    'p3'
```

Comment: this time you didn't resist to give an answer :P :)

Comment: I know, I'm ashamed.  :(  I eventually answered the other one, after I saw two other answers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, in fact I've and I know only the exclued list, this work very fine: rowsOut = M(~ismember(M(:,1),{'p1','p4'}),:)